# The best way to resolve ambiguity for hexadecimal versus decimal strings

Tags: string, parsing, hex

Let's say I want to accept user input as a string -- and it can either be a decimal or hexadecimal string -- and then I want to parse it into an integer.

The problem is, for some strings this is ambiguous: `"12345"`, `"00001"`, and other short strings with no "letter" digits.

So, I'd like to allow some way for the users to disambiguate those strings. Obviously they can prefix with `"0x"` if the string is actually supposed to be a hexadecimal integer, but if it's supposed to be decimal what should they do?

This seems like such a common problem, it must've been solved before.

Is there some sort of standard that's been adopted?

Comment: I think the common solution is to assume decimal unless told otherwise.

Comment: `h` suffix for hexadecimal is not unknown.

Comment: @rici yeah, I think so too. But the whole reason we are tackling this problem is to resolve unclear behavior from the system. We don't want people to ever accidentally input one format of number and have it be interpreted as the other, so if it's ambiguous we want to error out.

Comment: @NHDaly: Well, I'd say that is an uncommon problem. The standard, such as it is, is that numbers without annotation are decimal. It's tenfingerism, I know, so it's possibly politically incorrect, but that's the way we are. Some languages use the notation `<base>#<number>`, but you still need to impose tenfingerism on the `<base>` and the politically correct will note that every base is `10` in its own lovely writing system.

Comment: @rici: haha +1 for "every base is `10` in its own lovely writing system".

But okay, yeah, that's fair. Thanks!